# Records not showing after adding nameserver in cyberpanel

Tags: dns, domain-name, nameservers, cyber-panel

I am trying to set up a custom nameserver in `Cyberpanel`, the following is what I've done:

- I have a GoDaddy account which have my primary domain(e.g `primarydomain.com`), the nameservers for this domain(`primarydomain.com`) is managed by Godaddy, I've added two 'A' records, this points to the IP address where my `Cyberpanel` is installed (its a digital ocean droplet, all required ports are open):
  [image]
- Then i have added the nameserver details(of primarydomain.com) into the cyberpanel (i've followed these steps: https://forums.cyberpanel.net/discussion/257/super-simple-nameserver-creation) and it also tells me that nameservers have been added successfully.
- Also the DNS zone is added (because when i try to add it shows dupliacation error)

But the issue is after successful addition of nameservers(as follows):
[image]

when I try to check if they are added successfully or not (via going into menu DNS -> Add/Delete Records) it shows nothing:
[image]

I've tried following the following tuts:

- https://forums.cyberpanel.net/discussion/257/super-simple-nameserver-creation
- https://cyberpanel.net/docs/1-manage-dns/

I've almost created and destroyed 3 droplets thinking it might be the issue with cyber panel installation.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: I’m having the same issue with a new Vultr instance, first time trying CyberPanel.